# Redis as a Sidecar to a Container/POD?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, sidecar

I have a need to run two services within a container/POD ...

```
1. An App
2. Redis - the App uses it
```

Is it possible, say by making the Redis a Sidecar?

Comment: Are you sure that you want an redis instance per app instance? Shouldn't all app instances use the same redis-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to make a two-container pod, something like this:

```
    containers:
  - name: 1st
    image: redis
...
  - name: 2nd
    image: app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it if you want to tie the lifecycle of redis with single instance of your app. You just need to create a pod with multiple containers. You can access redis on `localhost` from your app if they are running in same pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/#creating-a-pod-that-runs-two-containers

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: myapp
  - name: redis
    image: redis
```

Your question sounds more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not make redis as a separate pod and access it via a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)? That way you can scale your app independently.

Comment: Yes, agreed, 1-1 container-service is indeed ideal, but my somewhat awkward use-case requirement necessitated two containers.